# What for does calling the each function on an array returns the array

Tags: ruby

Unlike any other method, `each` returns the receiver. What's the point of loops that return the receiver? Are there specific intended uses to something like this:

```
([1,2,3,4,5].each do |e| end).send(:some_method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` is executed solely for its side-effect. Its return value is meaningless. It *could* return `nil`, but why not simply return `self`, in case you want to do something else with it?

And by the way, `each` is certainly not the only method that returns its receiver. `<<` for example, usually also does that, at least for `Array`, `String` and co. (Not for `Integer`, though.)

Comment: That was my point exactly.  Your answer doesn't differ very much from Anthony's IMHO

Comment: I see little in common between the two answers. Also, aside from the substance of the question, only this one refutes an incorrect statement made by the OP

Comment: @CarySwoveland are you sure they have little in common?  I just saw `array` and `each` in the same sentences with a bunch of other words so I figured I believed in my gut 'cause grandma told me to.

Comment: @believesInSanta: the accepted answer mainly talks about "mutating the caller", which I don't even know what that means. Mutating the calling method? Mutating the calling object? While it is in some sense true that `each` does not do that, that's a rather trivial answer: this is impossible in Ruby, so *of course* `each` doesn't do that, and there is no need to explicitly call that fact out with a special return value.

Comment: @believesInSanta: but it is *impossible* to "mutate the caller" in Ruby (whatever that even means, monkeypatching the calling method?), so there simply is no need to return anything to check against that. It just doesn't make sense. The return value of `each` has nothing to do with what it does, `each` can return anything it wants, so it might just as well return something that is more useful than `nil`, and returning `self` is useful for method chaining.

Comment: @believesInSanta: to put it another way: if Ruby had statements, or methods that don't return anything (e.g. `void` methods), then `each` would be a statement or a `void` method. But since it returns something anyway, you can get creative with what makes it easiest to use. `puts` simply returns `nil`. But `p`, which is intended for debugging, returns its arguments, so you can easily insert it into an existing expression for debugging purposes without having to change your code. `def` returns the name of the method as a `Symbol`, so you can do `private def foo`. And so on.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sure, you can create an array `arr = [1,2,3]` and insert a new item in it each iteration `arr.each do { arr << 0 }`.  And I agree with what you are saying about ruby functions naturally returning stuff.  It makes sense that as a rubyist you just got to make the best of it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's why I told the other guy who deleted his answer receiver mutating iterations are no good.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) returns self at the end of the method invocation to showcase that the caller of the function was not mutated in any way.  The block you call with each is actually discarded after it reaches termination.

Comment: In what way does `Array#map` mutate the caller? That isn't even possible without heavy interpreter-specific metaprogramming hacks.

Answer (score 1):

For a given array of integers, suppose you wanted to do two things:

- double the value of each element in place; and
- sum the doubled values.

One way to do this is as follows:

```
def doit(arr)
  i = 0
  arr.each { |e| arr[i] = 2*e; i += 1 }.reduce(:+)
end

sum = doit(arr) #=> 12 
arr             #=> [2, 4, 6]
```

Now let's consider another question. We want to print three times each element of `arr` and return the sum of its values:

```
def doit(arr)
  arr.each { |e| puts 3*e }.reduce(:+)
end

sum = doit(arr)
  #  6
  # 12
  # 18
  #=> 12
```

In a comment on @sawa's since-deleted answer, the believer expressed his/her dismay over "modifying the elements of an array during iteration", which would apply equally to the first of my two examples.

Why should I have to confine myself to examples that we can all agree represent good programming practice? The point is that Ruby let's us do this, and we could not do it if `each` did not return the (possibly modified) receiver. Isn't that enough?